# I am getting the error ' AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401' on my nodeJS server

Tags: node.js, express, http, backend

I am starting out with learning full-stack development, and I was trying to create a nodeJS backend to access the OpenWeatherMap API and return the weather info for a particular city. My code is as follows:

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const weatherRoute = require("./routes/weather");
require('dotenv').config();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});

app.use("/api",weatherRoute);
```

**weather.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const router = express.Router();
require("dotenv").config();

const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY;

router.get("/weather", async (req, res) => {
  //Extract city name from request
  // const city = req.query.city;
  const city = `cochin`;
  try {
    //Get weather data
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&limit=5`;
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
    };
    const response = await axios.get(url, { headers });
    const weatherData = response.data;

    //Send weather data as JSON
    res.json(weatherData);
  } catch (error) {
    //Error
    console.error("Error sending weather data", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: `Unable to send weather data: ${error}` });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**.env**

```
API_KEY = XX_API_KEY_XX
```

I am getting the error "{"error":"Unable to send weather data: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401"}"

I had originally written the axios fetch code like:

```
const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&limit=5&appid=${apiKey}`;
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const weatherData = response.data;
```

giving the API key as a part of the URL, instead of defining it explicitly. Is this wrong? I got the same error in both cases.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong and how I can correct it.

I was expecting to get a weather info JSON like this:

```
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": 76.2602,
        "lat": 9.9399
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 804,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "overcast clouds",
            "icon": "04d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 304.14,
        "feels_like": 311.14,
        "temp_min": 303.16,
        "temp_max": 304.14,
        "pressure": 1009,
        "humidity": 77,
        "sea_level": 1009,
        "grnd_level": 1008
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 5.36,
        "deg": 306,
        "gust": 6.79
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 94
    },
    "dt": 1691925251,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 9211,
        "country": "IN",
        "sunrise": 1691887554,
        "sunset": 1691932449
    },
    "timezone": 19800,
    "id": 1273874,
    "name": "Kochi",
    "cod": 200
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [docs](https://openweathermap.org/current#geo), include your API key in the url parameter instead:

```
const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&limit=5&appid=${apiKey}`;

const response = await axios.get(url);
```

And make sure the API key is correct (it shouldn't have semicolon..)

(Try hardcoding apiKey)

```
const apiKey = 'XXXXX';
```

Comment: I tried hardcoding the apiKey as you suggested, and it finally worked. But, since this is not in accordance with the best practices, how can I use string interpolation to pass the API key?

Comment: I think the problem is that in your .env file, you have a semicolon, did you remove it? because, it should work  as is without the semicolon

Comment: I just did. Thanks! it's working now.